# Configuring Sonar Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Jenkins as continuous integration tool with SVN and configured SONAR to analyze the code.

I installed SONAR server and configured the SONAR URL in Jenkins.

But, I am not able to see that my code base is being linked with SONAR. When I click on sonar link from my JOB created in Jenkins, I am able to see the SONAR page but not my packages/classes.

Any Idea/Suggestion?

Comment: You haven't indicated what build technology you're using. The Jenkins plugin for Sonar works best with Maven. For example if you're using ANT you need to specify additional properties detailing the location of your source code (with ANT it's prob best to use the ANT plugin for Sonar)

Comment: @Mark: I am using Maven to build the project

Comment: Please add more information on how you set up your environment. FYI, everything is very well explained here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+Sonar+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonaronJenkinsJob-TriggeringaSonarAnalysiswithMaven